# Scrape data which gets loaded in later with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape the website gogoanime with Cheerio js. So far a lot works, until I ran into a wall. I want to scrape some data which gets loaded in later by JavaScript. I know that cheerio saves the source code. And in the source code we can see this:

```html
<div class="main_body">
    <div class="anime_name episode_video">
        <div class="anime_name_img_episode_video"></div>
            <h2>Episodes</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
        <div class="anime_video_body" id="episode_wrapper">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

The data I want to scrape gets loaded in later inside the #episode_wrapper. This will be loaded in:

```html
<ul data-range="0" style="display:block">
                                <li>
                <a data-name="1:01" data-name-normalized="1" href="/anime/my-hero-academia-dub-jwwn/ep-1" class="active" data-servers="28,40,35">
                    EP 01
                </a>
            </li>
                                            <li>
                <a data-name="2:02" data-name-normalized="2" href="/anime/my-hero-academia-dub-jwwn/ep-2" data-servers="28,40,35">
                    EP 02
                </a>
            </li>

...
</ul>
```

So I know that I must wait for the data to be loaded in before scraping the page. But this can't be done with Cheerio I think. But I saw this repository where the developer also uses Cheerio:

See the function: animeContentHandler.
https://github.com/ChrisMichaelPerezSantiago/gogoanime/blob/master/src/api/api.js

I honestly don't understand why he can scrape it with Cheerio. When I try to scrape the elements, I can't find the data containing all the episodes.

**What is the best way going forward? What is the best way to scrape the data that gets loaded in later? And can someone explain to me why it works for him and not for me.**

I appreciate all the help!

Comment: Are u using `fetch` or `axios` to make request? If u could share some code that might be helpful as well

Comment: What's the url? Load it chrome with the network tab open and search for the data to find out where it is.

Comment: @ShivamSood I'm using Axios, my code: https://github.com/buzzzlightyear/gogoanime/blob/search/src/scraper.js

Comment: @pguardiario the url of the site I'm trying to scrape is: https://gogoanime.pro/anime/my-hero-academia-dub-jwwn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the episode data, it's coming from this xhr:

https://gogoanime.pro/ajax/film/servers/jwwn?ep=&episode=

You could also use puppeteer to get it all in one go.

Comment: Thanks man, this really solved my problem and betters my understandings!!